# Moving all directories into a folder, shut down my linux server

Tags: centos, ssh, wordpress

SO recently I tried moving all files in a directory into a directory within the file path I was requesting everything to move from. From the directory `/srv/www/wptestsite` I ran the command

```
sudo mv ./* /wordpress
```

to move everything in the current directory (including Wordpress) into `wordpress`.

What I think happened is that it moved everything from root into a directory `wordpress`. What ended up happening was that I got disconnected from the server and now I cannot `ssh` or `ftp` into the IP address. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I thought of safe boot command line `ssh`, reinstall OS, or safe boot

Something to get me in and fix the problem or just reset with a fresh Linux server with CentOS 7 installed.

FTP or `ping`ing the server IP address doesn't work.

Comment: What directory were you in when you ran the `mv` command?

Comment: "_What I think happened is that it moved everything from root into a file `wordpress`_". Rest assured that if `wordpress` was a file the command would have failed. If it was a directory though then yes, files and folders would have been moved.

Comment: @roaima I was in /srv/www/wptestsite, and you are right wordpress IS a directory

Answer (score 0):

If you ran `sudo mv ./* /wordpress` from the `/srv/www/wptestsite` directory then you might have filled up the root directory's filesystem (`/`).

I don't think this should have caused the system to fail to boot, but it might have caused some of the more critical services to fail to start.

Depending on what "safe boot" really means you should be able to use that to get to the filesystems and move the files from `/wordpress` back to `/src/www/wptestsite`. I would not recommend a reinstallation of the OS.

Comment: Of course, if OP actually typed ``sudo mv /* /wordpress`` (or even ``sudo mv . /* /wordpress``), that would explain a broken system.